# Swift - Filtering an array of objects based upon its child array of orders?

Tags: arrays, swift, functional-programming, filtering, flatmap

I'm wanting to filter a `parent` array of locomotives based on its `children` array;

ie: Find all `locomotives` that have `orders`; only if the orders have an enum state of '1' or '2'; and I am using functional code to try to filter the array.

I have an array of Locomotives

```
var locomotives = [Locomotive]
```

Each Locomotive has an array of orders

```
class Locomotive {
    var order: [Order] = [Order]()
    var state: Int
}
```

An order is a struct

```
enum OrderState: Int {
   case initial, existing, sold
}

struct Order {
 var state: OrderState = .initial
 var value: Int
}
```

I wish to filter the array `locomotives` based and only return those Locomotives with orders that have the `order.state` of 1 or 2 only.

However my functional code returns an array of `orders` not an array of `locomotives`

```
let filter = locos
    .filter { (locomotive: Locomotive) -> Bool in
        return (locomotive.orders.count > 0)
    }
    .flatMap { (locomotive: Locomotive) -> [Order] in
        locomotive.orders
            .filter { (o: Order) -> Bool in
                return o.state == .existing || o.state == .sold
            }
    }
```

This returns an array of `[Order]` rather than an expected array of `[Locomotive]`

I'm wondering how I can make the above functional code give me a list of locomotives that:

- Have orders (where the orders.count > 0)
- Filter it upon the child array of `orders`

---

Further edit:

I was able to do a sort of hack to add a `lazy var` in my locomotive class

```
class Locomotive {
    lazy var existingOrders: [Order] = {
        return self.orders.filter { (o: Order) -> Bool in
            return o.state == .existingOrder
        }
    }()
    lazy var completedOrders: [Order] = {
        return self.orders.filter { (o: Order) -> Bool in
            return o.state == .completedOrder
        }
    }()
// ...
}
```

and then in my filter I can do a check on the lazy var

```
 let filter = locos
            .filter { (locomotive: Locomotive) -> Bool in
                return (
                    ((locomotive.existingOrders.count > 0) ||
                    (locomotive.completedOrders.count > 0))
                )
            }
// ....
```

But I'll review better ways to do it.

Comment: This is irrelevant, but `var state: Int  // State can be 0, 1 or 2` is not good Swift. If something can have just three discrete values, it should be an enum.

Comment: It is an enum in my actual program; I'm just using an Integer in this question to reduce verboseness.  I've now added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't try to map to Order, that is why you get the wrong type of result. Instead you can filter directly on Locomotive, for instance

```
locomotives.filter { !$0.order.isEmpty && $0.order.contains(where: { order in order.state > 0 }) }
```

Comment: I'll give it a go

Comment: Although I had to change it to `$0.order` to `$0.orders`, I was able to get it to work for my requirements; thank you!   Accepted.